# Alterações no log de erro

Tags: php, log

Por padrão quando tem algum erro no meu PHP, meu servidor cria um arquivo de log, com as seguintes informações:

> [19-Apr-2017 16:20:12 America/Fortaleza] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/Produto.php on line 131

Ele me informa qual o arquivo contém o erro, e qual a linha.
Porém queria saber se existe alguma formar de salvar a linha no log, ou seja, salvar a linha inteira que contém o erro.

Comment: Você quer salvar o conteúdo da linha que deu erro?

Comment: isso mesmo. é possível?

Comment: Não sei responder á tua pergunta, mas o próprio log já é uma ajuda para um atacante perceber como o sistema funciona por isso colocando o código fonte ainda mais exposto o seu sistema fica. Qual é a real necessidade de colocar o código fonte no log? O número da linha não é suficiente?

Comment: Abra o arquivo com as funções normais(fopen) e pule para a linha que indicar no log padrão.

Comment: @lazyFox mas como um atacante tem acesso ao log? achei que so eu tinha acesso a ele, uma vez que ele fica em uma pasta onde eu acesso via ftp. Utilizo ele para identificar possíveis problemas com o sistema.

Comment: @LucasTorres não entendi muito bem o que vc pediu para eu fazer

Comment: Veja, ao invés do "error" padrão, você quer exatamente o conteúdo da linha informada no log, certo?

Comment: não queria o erro é o conteúdo da linha, eu pensei em criar uma função personalizada para criar log, isso eu até sei fazer, o problema é como chagar a função quando houver um erro no php.

Comment: Experimenta este artigo: [How to perform error handling](https://web.stanford.edu/dept/its/communications/webservices/wiki/index.php/How_to_perform_error_handling_in_PHP) Na secção **Create a custom error handler**

Comment: Também aconselho a veres [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Answer (score 0):

Pata atingires esse objectivo podes fazer uso da função [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) em junção com a função [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Fiz uma pesquisa e encontrei uma solução no [stackoverflow vizinho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159216/how-can-i-get-php-to-produce-a-backtrace-upon-errors), segue o código:

```
<?php
function process_error_backtrace($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext) {
    if(!(error_reporting() & $errno))
        return;
    switch($errno) {
    case E_WARNING      :
    case E_USER_WARNING :
    case E_STRICT       :
    case E_NOTICE       :
    case E_USER_NOTICE  :
        $type = 'warning';
        $fatal = false;
        break;
    default             :
        $type = 'fatal error';
        $fatal = true;
        break;
    }
    $trace = array_reverse(debug_backtrace());
    array_pop($trace);
    if(php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
        echo 'Backtrace from ' . $type . ' \'' . $errstr . '\' at ' . $errfile . ' ' . $errline . ':' . "\n";
        foreach($trace as $item)
            echo '  ' . (isset($item['file']) ? $item['file'] : '<unknown file>') . ' ' . (isset($item['line']) ? $item['line'] : '<unknown line>') . ' calling ' . $item['function'] . '()' . "\n";
    } else {
        echo '<p class="error_backtrace">' . "\n";
        echo '  Backtrace from ' . $type . ' \'' . $errstr . '\' at ' . $errfile . ' ' . $errline . ':' . "\n";
        echo '  <ol>' . "\n";
        foreach($trace as $item)
            echo '    <li>' . (isset($item['file']) ? $item['file'] : '<unknown file>') . ' ' . (isset($item['line']) ? $item['line'] : '<unknown line>') . ' calling ' . $item['function'] . '()</li>' . "\n";
        echo '  </ol>' . "\n";
        echo '</p>' . "\n";
    }
    if(ini_get('log_errors')) {
        $items = array();
        foreach($trace as $item)
            $items[] = (isset($item['file']) ? $item['file'] : '<unknown file>') . ' ' . (isset($item['line']) ? $item['line'] : '<unknown line>') . ' calling ' . $item['function'] . '()';
        $message = 'Backtrace from ' . $type . ' \'' . $errstr . '\' at ' . $errfile . ' ' . $errline . ': ' . join(' | ', $items);
        error_log($message);
    }
    if($fatal)
        exit(1);
}

set_error_handler('process_error_backtrace');
?>
```